# how to know how many words contains in UITextView

Tags: xcode, swift, text, swift2, uisearchcontroller

I am making `UISearchController` with google search. And I face with problem, how many words contain in `UISearchBar.text` that I will can make different actions. Or how to separate different words are separated space?
Also I want to know, how to count words in `UITextView`.

My try

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let text = searchController.searchBar.text!
    if text.containsString("www.") {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://\(text)")!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    } else {
        if text.containsString(" ") == false {
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=\(text)")!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        } else {
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&q=\(text)")! // it is wrong
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
            print("two words")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I got it, NSString's componentsSeparatedByString will do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misread your question...

```
//Separate all words into an array
let allText = SearchText.text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

//then count the array
var wordsCount:Int = allText.count
```

To count chars of a UITextView.text you could use `count(UISearchBar.text)`